# React JS: Passing values when back button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am creating a website using React JS to allow users to click on a brand and scrape images from Instagram. On the landing page **/landing**, the user can select a brand and this brand name is passed to the Instagram scraper page **/instagramScraper**:

```
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/instagramScraper',
      params: {
        brandName: this.state.brand_name
      }
    });
```

The instagram scraper page gets the brandName using the following code:

```
this.state.brandName = props.location.params["brandName"];
```

The user is now able to click on an image on this **/instagramScraper** and is brought to another page **/editPhoto** where the image can be edited. After selecting the "back button" from **/editPhoto**, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'brandName' of undefined new Landing

src/components/instagramScraper.js:24
  21 |   this.onAddImages = this.onAddImages.bind(this);
  22 |   this.onScrape = this.onScrape.bind(this);
  23 |   this.learnMore = this.learnMore.bind(this);
> 24 |   this.state.brandName = props.location.params["brandName"];
```

How can I pass in the brandName param when the back button is selected from the photoEdit page? I have tried using this.setState in the landing page, however the value of the brandName gets reset.

Comment: Looks like that when `back` is clicked, instead of the URL looking like `/instagramScraper/brandName`, it looks like `/instagramScraper`. Is this correct?

Comment: @Rush a total typo on my part when replicating the code. When _back_ is clicked on /landing/instagramScraper/editPhoto, it looks at /landing/instagramScrape' but the **brandName** parameter in /landing/instagramScraper which is passed in by /landing is undefined

Comment: Are you using a routing package such as `react-router`?

Comment: Not currently. Is that something I would need to use?

Comment: It should be fine without it.

Is the order and url structure below correct?:
1) on `/landing`
2) click a brand which takes you to `/landing/instagramScraper/brandName`
3) click image which takes you to `/landing/instagramScraper/editPhoto`
4) Click back

Comment: brandName is the parameter passed which you click on a brand on /landing. After you click a brand, you are directed to /landing/instagramScraper and brandName is passed as a parameter

Comment: Okay got it. So since you are passing it as parameter, when you go `back`, that parameter is lost. Along with parameter, could you also use a query string or part of the url path? E.g. `/landing/instagramScraper/brandName` or `/landing/instagramScraper?brandName=NAME`. This will help you preserve the info in the location history and then the `back` would work. Other option is to use `react-router` which helps with routing on a React SPA and it would take care of the state.

Comment: That is a great solution!! Thank you so much. If you answer below, I’ll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So since you are passing it as parameter, when you go back, that parameter is lost. Along with parameter, could you also use a query string or part of the url path? E.g. `/landing/instagramScraper/brandName` or `/landing/instagramScraper?brandName=NAME`. This will help you preserve the info in the location history and then the back would work. Other option is to use react-router which helps with routing on a React SPA and it would take care of the state.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
this.state = {
  brandName: ...
}
```

instead of `this.state.brandName = ...` in your constructor

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I am still getting the same error when I use the following in the constructor:

this.state = {
    brandName: props.location.params["brandName"]
}